# Errors in installing django module for python

Tags: python

I've been trying to install django, looked around the internet but couldn't find possible solution for this.

I have tried looking for solutions. Some solutions told me to install conflict checker for pip but it still did not work because nothing seems to be getting installed using 'pip' keyword. It even gives me error when I try to find out my pip version

```
python -m pip install django



PS C:\Users\Fahad> python -m pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fahad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Fahad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Fahad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Fahad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3



PS C:\Users\Fahad> python -m pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fahad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Fahad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Fahad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Fahad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3'
```

Comment: Are you trying to install Python (as per your first sentence), or Django?

Comment: googling your error message, I found this: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6261 as one of the very first results.

Comment: @ncica his pip package is broken so he can NOT use pip !

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That's on linux, and not about urllib3.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6010 (but unanswered since November 2018).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You can install `pip` *without* using `pip` itself (the pip creates were not that crazy that they demand an impossible loop).

Comment: pip installs automatically when we install python, right?

Comment: Where did you install Python 3.7 itself from?

Comment: I'm on windows, not linux btw, that github link is for linux..  @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: @9769953 from python's official website

Comment: @9769953  "That's on linux, and not about urllib3." => and ? The issue is obviously similar... "You can install pip without using pip itself " => I know thanks - but what you cannot do is using a broken pip to reinstall pip (which is what I was responding to)

Comment: @FahadAzeem what make you think  that the OS is relevant here ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers because I tried the solution given in that link. See this https://imgur.com/nHincUH

Comment: @FahadAzeem then why didn't you mention it in your question ??? But the bug report is STILL relevant - you just need to use the proper windows tools / commands to clean up the broken install - you can't obviously expect bash shell commands to work on a windows command prompt ! Oh and yes, __read the full bug report__ : btw you DONT want to remove the whole site-packages directory, only the "pip" directory itself.

Comment: Python 3.7 should come with `pip` provided. The fact that you promptly run into this issue, indicates a (severe) mismatch between the Python installation with this version of pip.

Comment: I would simply try to install pip from scratch *over* your current installation: it should overwrite the relevant directory/ies. Unfortunately, the [installation instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) appear to be a bit Linux/MacOS/terminal centric (not sure if curl is available by default on Windows 10), but you can just download the `get-pip.py` script from the given URL, then execute the `python3.7 get-pip.py` command.

Comment: Thanks @9769953 your answer helped me and it worked. How do I close this question now?

Comment: You can actually self-answer it with the details of what you've done. That will help other people in the future that stumble upon the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried downloading get-pip.py from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and hen I executed python get-pip.py then I tried re-installing django and it worked.